# Custom Drawing View load drawable image inside it

Tags: android, canvas

I've searched, but haven't found anything I'm looking for, perhaps. I want load image into my custom drawing view. Here is the code of DrawingView that extend View.

```
    private Path mDrawPath;
    private Paint mBackgroundPaint;
    private Paint mDrawPaint;
    private Canvas mDrawCanvas;
    private Bitmap mCanvasBitmap;

    private ArrayList<Path> mPaths = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Paint> mPaints = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Path> mUndonePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Paint> mUndonePaints = new ArrayList<>();

    // Set default values
    private int mBackgroundColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private int mPaintColor = 0xFF660000;
    private int mStrokeWidth = 10;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        mDrawPath = new Path();
        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
        initPaint();
    }

    private void initPaint()
    {
        mDrawPaint = new Paint();
        mDrawPaint.setColor(mPaintColor);
        mDrawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mDrawPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
        mDrawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mDrawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mDrawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas)
    {
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mBackgroundPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
        mBackgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), mBackgroundPaint);

    }

    private void drawPaths(Canvas canvas)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (Path p : mPaths)
        {
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaints.get(i));
            i++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        drawBackground(canvas);
        drawPaths(canvas);

        canvas.drawPath(mDrawPath, mDrawPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        mDrawCanvas = new Canvas(mCanvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mDrawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                //mDrawPath.addCircle(touchX, touchY, mStrokeWidth/10, Path.Direction.CW);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mDrawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mDrawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                mPaths.add(mDrawPath);
                mPaints.add(mDrawPaint);
                mDrawPath = new Path();
                initPaint();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void clearCanvas()
    {
        mPaths.clear();
        mPaints.clear();
        mUndonePaths.clear();
        mUndonePaints.clear();
        mDrawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setPaintColor(int color)
    {
        mPaintColor = color;
        mDrawPaint.setColor(mPaintColor);
    }

    public void setPaintStrokeWidth(int strokeWidth)
    {
        mStrokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        mDrawPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int color)
    {
        mBackgroundColor = color;
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
        invalidate();
    }



    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        drawBackground(mDrawCanvas);
        drawPaths(mDrawCanvas);
        return mCanvasBitmap;
    }

    public void undo()
    {
        if (mPaths.size() > 0)
        {
            mUndonePaths.add(mPaths.remove(mPaths.size() - 1));
            mUndonePaints.add(mPaints.remove(mPaints.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void redo()
    {
        if (mUndonePaths.size() > 0)
        {
            mPaths.add(mUndonePaths.remove(mUndonePaths.size() - 1));
            mPaints.add(mUndonePaints.remove(mUndonePaints.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

BoardActivity class code is:

```
 private TextView titolo;
private DrawingView areaDisegno;
private ImageView sceltaColore, sceltaSpessore, undo, redo;
private Bitmap drawable;

private int mCurrentBackgroundColor;
private int mCurrentColor;
private int mCurrentStroke;
private static final int MAX_STROKE_WIDTH = 50;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_board1);

    titolo = findViewById(R.id.titolo);

    titolo.setText("MATCHUP BOARD 1");

    areaDisegno = findViewById(R.id.area_disegno);
    sceltaColore= findViewById(R.id.scelta_colore);
    sceltaSpessore = findViewById(R.id.scelta_spessore);
    undo = findViewById(R.id.undo);
    redo = findViewById(R.id.redo);

    sceltaColore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startColorPickerDialog();
        }
    });

    sceltaSpessore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startStrokeSelectorDialog();
        }
    });

    undo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            areaDisegno.undo();
        }
    });

    redo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            areaDisegno.redo();;
        }
    });

    inizializzaAreaDisegno();


}

private void inizializzaAreaDisegno()
{
 //   mCurrentBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white);
    mCurrentColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black);
    mCurrentStroke = 10;

    areaDisegno.setBackgroundColor(mCurrentBackgroundColor);
    areaDisegno.setPaintColor(mCurrentColor);
    areaDisegno.setPaintStrokeWidth(mCurrentStroke);
}

private void startFillBackgroundDialog()
{
    int[] colors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.palette);

    ColorPickerDialog dialog = ColorPickerDialog.newInstance(R.string.color_picker_default_title,
            colors,
            mCurrentBackgroundColor,
            5,
            ColorPickerDialog.SIZE_SMALL);

    dialog.setOnColorSelectedListener(new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onColorSelected(int color)
        {
            mCurrentBackgroundColor = color;
            areaDisegno.setBackgroundColor(mCurrentBackgroundColor);
        }

    });

    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "ColorPickerDialog");
}

private void startColorPickerDialog()
{
    int[] colors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.palette);

    ColorPickerDialog dialog = ColorPickerDialog.newInstance(R.string.color_picker_default_title,
            colors,
            mCurrentColor,
            5,
            ColorPickerDialog.SIZE_SMALL);

    dialog.setOnColorSelectedListener(new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onColorSelected(int color)
        {
            mCurrentColor = color;
            areaDisegno.setPaintColor(mCurrentColor);
        }

    });

    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "ColorPickerDialog");
}

private void startStrokeSelectorDialog()
{
    StrokeSelectorDialog dialog = StrokeSelectorDialog.newInstance(mCurrentStroke, MAX_STROKE_WIDTH);

    dialog.setOnStrokeSelectedListener(new StrokeSelectorDialog.OnStrokeSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onStrokeSelected(int stroke)
        {
            mCurrentStroke = stroke;
            areaDisegno.setPaintStrokeWidth(mCurrentStroke);
        }
    });

    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "StrokeSelectorDialog");
}

private void startShareDialog(Uri uri)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
}

private void requestPermissionsAndSaveBitmap()
{
    if (PermissionManager.checkWriteStoragePermissions(this))
    {
        Uri uri = FileManager.saveBitmap(this, areaDisegno.getBitmap());
        startShareDialog(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case PermissionManager.REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE:
        {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Uri uri = FileManager.saveBitmap(this, areaDisegno.getBitmap());
                startShareDialog(uri);
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Layout used is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo"
    tools:context=".activities.Board1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_menu_disegno"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2"
            >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_weight="1.99"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" >

                <it.colan.matchup.ui.component.DrawingView
                    android:id="@+id/area_disegno"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:src="@drawable/board_1" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_strumenti"
                android:layout_weight="0.01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/area_disegno"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/black">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scelta_colore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_palette"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scelta_spessore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_peso_linea"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/undo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_undo"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/redo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_redo"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have two problems:

1. The drawing does it for me behind the image and not above

[imagebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaGhw.png)

2. The background of the image is not full screen with margins.

How should I do?
Thanks
Cris

Comment: Anyone... any ideas?

Comment: Just solved. But i don't say how. Bye bye. >:) Bwuhahahahahaaaa